# How to find the $k$ coefficient for the equation $kx^2 + x + k = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Exercise from Sullivan's Algebra & Trigonometry book:
Chapter 1.3) Exercise 113...

> Find $k$ such that the equation $kx^2 + x + k = 0$ has repeated real
>   solutions.

I've tried to pass the $+k$ to the right and complete the square, using the quadratic formula, and grouping... the most I've reached to solve it was this expression $(\sqrt kx+\frac{1}{2\sqrt k})^2=\frac{1}{4k}-k$. But don't really know I even have to do anything like that.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know the quadratic formula? You will have to explain more about why you have difficulty with this to get a helpful answer.

Comment: done, don't know if that's enough.

Comment: okay, what should be the quadratic equation discriminant value for getting repeated roots?

Comment: So for a repeated root you need the expression on the right-hand side to equal $0$ so that the factorisation is of the form $y^2=0$, which has the single solution $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quadratic has a repeated root, then both its roots must be the same, in which case its discriminant is equal to zero.  The discriminant of the quadratic equation
$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0, a \neq 0$$
is 
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$$
Can you take it from there?